# Future editable select list option?

Tags: 7

I am building a car directory with 500+ car models x 10 years. Every car listing will have many computed fields calculating various aspects of car model like fuel cost, maintenance, insurance, model depreciation, price after 5 year etc.

Now in depreciation computed field it takes the set value from depreciation rate field (which is different for every car) while adding the car. This Depreciation is region specific and I might have to change or tweak few values as we progress based on people feedback, updated research etc. I need some solution, with which i can change the depreciation rate field and republish the nodes to take effect the new values. In current select list option i can't change any value once that value is in use.

I have tried Views batch update (as a tweak), and that's my last option if I can't get this functionality somehow.

Comment: so why not just convert the depreciation rate field from a select list to a float? your approach sounds right, the only issue seems to be the limitations of making this level of updates to a select list

Comment: @schnippy I am using select list-float (as i want dropdown) currently and can't update any term or value if its used.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the list field type, I'd suggest you to use taxonomy and term reference field. That way you can always update the referenced term independently, add new terms, delete terms etc.

1. Create a vocabulary for the field, for example, depreciation
2. Add as many terms as you want to have in the select list
3. Add a new field in your content type, and as field type select *Term reference*; as widget select *Select list*
4. In the field options you should assign the newly created vocabulary (e.g. depreciation) to that field

**UPDATE:**

I assume that you have

- a content type called 'car'
- a vocabulary called 'model'

You should create a new vocabulary for each list field that you need to make future editable/expandable. If I understood correctly, you want to have the 'depraciation rate' editable, so you should create a new vocabulary called `depreciation_rate`

1. Go to admin/structure/taxonomy/add
2. Name it 'Depreciation Rate' or whatever you like
3. Add as many terms as you want to have in your 'select list' field. The terms will be listed as options in that field.

Then, you need to create a field to reference this vocabulary on the car content type if depreciation rate is different for every car (or on the model vocabulary if the depreciation rate is different for every model).

1. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/car/fields
2. Add new field, name it 'Depraciation Rate' with the machine name 'field_depreciation_name', or whatever you like.
3. As field type select 'Term reference' and as widget 'Select list'
4. On the field settings, assign the vocabulary you created.

Comment: Thanks for advising, and i already tried using taxonomy in this scenario but unable to store value and call. Could you please explain how I can do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want like below and capability to change decimal values even if those fields are in use in future.

29.6|Term 1
35.8|Term 2
42.5|Term 3
69.8|Term 4
15.24|Term 5
13.68|Term 6

Comment: I tried creating additional field in Model vocabulary of depreciation and made it select list float as i want the choice of drop-down. Then in car content form called same field_depreciation. I hope this is what you meant by Term reference field??? However now half the problem is solved of freely editing or adding more terms as i need, but glitch of select list is still same of some limitation on characters. I load 352 cars name with depreciation and it shows me only 277...! Any idea how to fix this limitation. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I'll update my answer with clearer instructions.

Comment: Елин Й. Thanks for your detailed response but i still can't understand where to add the depreciation value in term reference. I achieve this yesterday and want to know if there is any downside of this way of managing this complex issue.

Comment: You should create a new term for each value you want to list in the select list field.

Comment: @ Елин Й Thanks for help, but if i create all values in taxonomy terms (parents+child) then where will the label goes? As intent of this field is to pick an appropriate depreciation percentage and use this field value in computed field. I want like this 70|Audi A1 where 70 being value getting used in computed field and Audi A1 is a label for choosing. I am really sorry to bug again and again, but can't find any way to store value in taxonomy terms. Thanks.

Comment: I'll take a deeper look in your case and give you feedback this evening, most probably in 5-6 hours.

Comment: @ Елин Й Gentle reminder, please.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I didn't have much time on the day before, but yesterday I was able to update my answer with more details.